# .htaccess not redirecting all traffic

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Im hoping some one can help.

Im using .htaccess to redirect all traffic to another website while i work on it ... It works great for the main index page, but anything else results in the redirection getting appened

For instance, www.website.com works perfect and gets redirected to www.google.com ... but when i go to www.website.com/wp-admin ... it gets redirected to www.google.comwp-admin

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

It all should redirect here -> http://www.myredirect.com/show.aspx?sh=KU14

Here is my line

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.myredirect.com/show.aspx?sh=KU14$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked to append the url to the redirected url `$1`. just remove it

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.myredirect.com/show.aspx?sh=KU14 [R=301,L]
```

*Note:* If you are trying to redirect for maintenance use `307` Temporary redirect. `301` is permanent redirect and browser may not visit your original site later, once you finish your update.

Quote from [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes)

> 301 Moved Permanently
>   This and all future requests should be directed to the given URI.[2]
>
> 307 Temporary Redirect (since HTTP/1.1)
>   In this case, the request
>   should be repeated with another URI; however, future requests should
>   still use the original URI.[2] In contrast to how 302 was historically
>   implemented, the request method is not allowed to be changed when
>   reissuing the original request. For instance, a POST request should be
>   repeated using another POST request.[11]

Comment: Thanks for that :) ... So i should change 301 to 307?